# How can I update redux state in Reducer in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Please know that I am new to ReactJS with Redux.

I have list of passengers, and each passenger has list of flights. I would like to update the flight property, `checkedIn` with the action property `isCheckedIn`. How can I achieve that with in reducer?

**reducer.js**

```
export default function passengerReducer(
  state = initialState.passengers,
  action
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_PASSENGERS_SUCCESS:
      return action.passengers;
    case types.UPDATE_PASSENGER_SUCCESS:
      console.log("action ", action.passengerData.passengerId);
      console.log("state ", state);
      return state
        .filter(x => x.id == action.passengerData.passengerId)
        .map(f => {
          f.flights[0].checkedIn = action.passengerData.isCheckedIn
        });

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The `state` contains array of objects. Each object also contains `flights`. At the moment, I am only focusing the first flight with in `flights` array.

[image]

The action contains `isCheckedIn` property. I would like to update `checkedIn`property of the `flights` with `isCheckedIn` property from action.

[image]

Comment: Hi could you share the initial state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is the piece of code in question I presume:

```
 case types.UPDATE_PASSENGER_SUCCESS:
  console.log("action ", action.passengerData.passengerId);
  console.log("state ", state);
  return state
    .filter(x => x.id == action.passengerData.passengerId)
    .map(f => {
      f.flights[0].checkedIn = action.passengerData.isCheckedIn
    });
```

You're (a) filtering the array only for the element you want to change, and (b) mapping that but not returning anything from your map function

Just (a) alone is bad -- you're going to change your entire state to only include the filtered items? I don't think that's what you intended. But then (b) means you're returning an array full of `undefined`

What you want to do, instead, is create a new array, `var newArray = state.slice(0);`

Then, find the index of the item you want to change the checked_in property of,

```
var index = newArray.findIndex(x => x.id == action.passengerData.passengerId);
var newPassenger = Object.assign({}, newArray[index]);
newPassenger.flights[0].checkedIn = action.passengerData.isCheckedIn;
newArray[index] = newPassenger;
return newArray;
```

So you've found the item you wanted to change, changed it, put it back in the array (this is the immutable way to do things, I think), and then returned the FULL array

Comment: I know you see lots of peoples Reducers using simple one-liner functional chains dealing with arrays, but you don't have to do that. Just remember: whatever you return from your reducer becomes THE ENTIRE STATE. So if you return a filtered array, the items that didn't come back with your filter are now not part of your entire state at all

Comment: It works. However, I have got the following error `Uncaught (in promise) Invariant Violation: A state mutation was detected inside a dispatch, in the path: `passengers.0.flights.0.seatNum`. Take a look at the reducer(s) handling the action {"type":"UPDATE_PASSENGER_SUCCESS","passengerData":{"passengerId":1,"seatNum":"A1","isCheckedIn":false}}.`

Comment: Yes, so what's happened is even though we made a copy of the array, and we made a copy of the Passenger, we DIDN'T make a copy of the flights. You might want to look into some sort of 'deepCopy' react package

Comment: I have used this, and no error `newPassenger = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newArray[index]))`